# Bar chart show values on top

Tags: d3.js

I am using mbostock's [bar chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304). The code is nearly the same. Instead of letter and frequency, I have name and value respectively. I want to display the value of each data on the bar. I tried adding this at the end.

```
svg.selectAll(".bar").append("text")
                     .attr("x", height/2)
                     .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value) - 3; })
                     .text(function(d) { return d.value; });
```

But that doesn't seem to work at all. So what have I messed up?

Comment: Don't append `text` to `rect` elements...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are appending the `text` to `rect` elements -- this isn't valid in SVG and the text won't show up. Instead, append the `text` either to a `g` element or the top-level SVG:

```
svg.selectAll("text.bar")
  .data(data)
.enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency) - 10; })
  .text(function(d) { return d.frequency; });
```

Complete demo [here](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/601c66edfb83a11cf2bb).

Comment: The code of the demo worked for me `.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter) + x.rangeBand()/2; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency) - 5; }) `  Without that the value is not centered to the bar